# How to convert the large bio-format file to database-like file that can be asynchronously accessed width JavaScript

Tags: php, d3.js, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format, bam

Pros!

I have a visualization project that render the biological data to canvas charts, in which I use a javascritp framwork called [jgv.js](https://github.com/igvteam/igv.js)(the [doc API](https://github.com/igvteam/igv.js/wiki)) to generate canvas.

**Here’s a simple config demo:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>IGV Data Vis</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="source/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="source/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="source/igv-1.0.1.css">
    <script src="source/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="source/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="source/igv-1.0.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>

    <script>
        let options = {
                palette: ["#00A0B0", "#6A4A3C", "#CC333F", "#EB6841"],
                locus: "7:55,085,725-55,276,031",

                reference: {
                    id: "hg19",
                    fastaURL: "//igv.broadinstitute.org/genomes/seq/1kg_v37/human_g1k_v37_decoy.fasta",
                    cytobandURL: "//igv.broadinstitute.org/genomes/seq/b37/b37_cytoband.txt"
                },

                trackDefaults: {
                    bam: {
                        coverageThreshold: 0.2,
                        coverageQualityWeight: true
                    }
                },

                tracks: [
                    {
                        name: "Genes",
                        url: "//igv.broadinstitute.org/annotations/hg19/genes/gencode.v18.collapsed.bed",
                        index: "//igv.broadinstitute.org/annotations/hg19/genes/gencode.v18.collapsed.bed.idx",
                        displayMode: "EXPANDED",
                        height: 350,
                        color: '#ff0000'
                    }
                ]
            };

        let browser = igv.createBrowser(document.getElementById('container'), options);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The items of **tracks** in the code above are bio-information statments that could be in the form of plain-text file or binary file(*.bam).

The problem is the bio files are so terible large that I can not access them directly, no mention for the clients. Such as:

- [**.bam**](https://www.plob.org/article/7234.html)  approximate 3G
- [**.vcf**](http://www.internationalgenome.org/wiki/Analysis/vcf4.0/)  approximate 1G

So, ***is there any back-end solutions to make those files accessable piece by piece?*** Just like the way of AJAX.

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: What do you have in those files? All the base pairs of the human genome?

Comment: @gerardoFurtado Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends of what you mean by 'piece by piece'.

Bam and vcf files use a bgzip format that can be accessed using random access. Even through the web has long as the hosting server supports the 'Byte-Range:' request.

```
$ tabix "http://igv.broadinstitute.org/annotations/hg19/genes/gencode.v18.collapsed.bed.gz" "1:40723778-40759856"

1   40723778    40759856    ZMPSTE24    1000.0  +   40723778    40759856    .   17  288,159,156,183,147,72,87,51,117,153,142,185,105,353,144,1740,177,  0,129,132,1243,2732,4727,9679,9679,10312,11868,13787,23236,27818,32538,32747,34338,34338,
1   40728343    40728656    RP1-39G22.4 1000.0  -   40728343    40728656    .   1   313,    0,
```

For bioinformatics, you can also ask biostars.org

Answer (score 0):

Too broad question. There are many ways to get a file by pieces. Php has a lot of functions to deal with files like `fseek` ([doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php)) or `fgets`. You'd better not transfer 3G of data to user, but do the calculations needed at your back-end.

Using any image library (gd2?) you can make the image base on the genome file on your server. No need to transfer a huge amount of data to a client.

Answer (score 0):

yes.
format bam dispicts the whole genome reads alignment details, so it is very large.
format vcf dispicts the whole genome SNP infos and thier respective annotations